# Grails java.sql.BatchUpdateException error using Hibernate/GORM

Tags: hibernate, exception, grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm using GORM to create some domain classes for a plugin I will use across multiple Grails 2.2.3 applications. For some reason, when I add a Getter to my Student domain class I get a BatchUpdateException telling me I don't have sufficient privileges to update.

Edit: Note that I am using the ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0 driver for Oracle 11g database.

Here is my Student class:

```
class Student {

    String sid
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String middleInitial
    String email
    String ssn

    static mapping = {
        // Mappings and such
    }
}
```

I am adding this Getter to "sanitize" the middle initial value I receive from the database on the chance that it is null:

```
String getMiddleInitial() {
    return this.middleInitial ?: ""
}
```

After adding that line, I navigate to the `/$app_name/student/list` URL and get the following error/stack trace:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
/appname/employee/list
Class
java.sql.BatchUpdateException
Message
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
Trace

   Line | Method
->> 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   918 | run     in     ''
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
->> 895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   918 | run     in     ''
^   680 | run . . in java.lang.Thread

Caused by BatchUpdateException: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

->> 10070 | executeBatch in oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   213 | executeBatch in oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper
|   297 | executeBatch in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement
|   895 | runTask in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run . . in     ''
^   680 | run     in java.lang.Thread
```

After removing that Getter, listing all of students in the database works just fine. This doesn't make any sense to me, because it isn't like I'm trying to update or save an object to the database. Can anyone explain what is going on and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have `dbCreate` set to `update` or `create` in `DataSource.groovy`?

If it is present, then remove or comment out that entry.

```
//dbCreate = 'update' //or use as below
dbCreate = 'none'
```

Comment: I had removed it, but I can try to explicitly set it to none.

Edit: No such luck. Same error. I thought Getters and Setters were supported in Grails domain classes if you want a little extra control over what gets set/returned?

Comment: @grantmc It should be an issue if `dbCreate` is not used. I had used `ojdbc14` and resolved the same issue following the same steps as above.

Comment: @grantmc Were you running tests or `run-app`? Check if you are commenting out under appropriate environment.

Comment: I have removed it from all environments. I am doing a run-app. It seems that adding `static transients = ['middleInitial']` fixed it for some reason...

Comment: @grantmc But that defies the purpose. `middleInitial` is the domain class property mapped to a column in db and should not be transient. right?

Comment: I suppose that is true, yes. So you think that removing dbCreate from all of my DataSource.groovy environments might do the trick?

Comment: @grantmc Nope, I did not mean that. I said whichever environment you are using. Normally, run-app uses `dev` environment, and test-app uses `test` environment.

Comment: @grantmc Isolate the problem by creating a sample grails app afresh and trying the above steps to see if you are able to replicate the issue initially and resolve it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem while flushing the session after every 100 rows. I turned on the SQL logging and hibernate logging. It turned out to be the grails session is trying to persist the unnecessary domain object which is in the session. I had to discard the object using domainObj.discard() before flushing the session. Then this error disappered.